# How do I specify custom settings for vim based on file path

Tags: vim, gvim, path, vimrc

More specifically, I want to disable backup and swap file creation in vim, but only when opening/editing files that are on a specific remote volume or a specific folder.

So, how do I go about disabling/enabling a set of options when opening a file in a specific location (not depending on the filetype)

Answer (score 2):

I did answer your question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456792/vim-apply-settings-on-files-in-directory/456889#456889

However, for remote files (you may have to add a pattern to an autocommand that will match external filenames).

Answer (score -2):

with `%` you can get info about file, example:

```
echo expand('%:p:h')
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation about what your code does? You've only explained `%`...